# How to connect a remote server to mongodb pod in open shift cluster using oc cli commands

Tags: mongodb, openshift, remote-server, portforwarding

I have a mongodb pod running in open shift cluster.

I want to connect to that mongodb from a remote server machine using oc cli command.
How can I do that

I searched over the net and found concept of port forwarding but that allows local app to connect to open shift mongo db.
Found this in blog

[Port-Forwarding Blog](https://tomd.xyz/openshift-dev-connect-database/)

I could not find how one can connect a remote server machine to mongodb pod which is present in openshift cluster using oc cli commands.

Any idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Is NodePort a solution you are looking for? If so, you can create it with oc cli command `oc create service nodeport`. Please find more details using help command.